# Django check for error messages in context

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a simple test:

```
def test_project_info_form_post_submission(self):
    """
    Test if project info form can be submitted via post.
    """
    # set up our POST data
    post_data = {
        'zipcode': '90210',
        'module': self.module1.pk,
        'model': self.model1.pk,
        'orientation': 1,
        'tilt': 1,
        'rails_direction': 1,
    }
    ...
    response = self.client.post(reverse(url), post_data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    # test empty form
    response = self.client.post(reverse(url))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    #! test for general form error message 

    # now test invalid responses
    post_data['zipcode'] = 'abcdefg'
    response = self.client.post(reverse(url), post_data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    #! test for specific error message associated with zipcode
```

So the lines I am having trouble with are marked with shebangs. I know I should have messages in the context variable but can't seem to figure out the right ones to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if the template contains your message in your TestCase with [`assertContains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.assertContains).